# Weird behavior while debugging in VS2008 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Today i was debugging some lines of code and i noticed a very weird behavior:

a declared variable should get a value returned from a method. The method returns properly (as expected) the value, but hovering over the variable name (after the assignment) returns ... absolutely NOTHING.

Even writing the variable's name in the watch window resulted in nothing: The name 'variableName' does not exist in the current context!! Not to mention that the variable was NOT listed in the local variables!!!

I thought "very strange", let's output the variable's content to Console .. et voila: not only the correct content was shown in the Console's window but there was also the value available hovering over the variable!!!!???!!!

Has anybody experienced something similar?? Is there something i have to adjust?? It's the first time i ran into such a situation!

I was seeking an non existing error which cost me a couple of hours...very very frustrating!

I'm using VS2008 .NET 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perhaps use a "Release" build? The compiler might have "optimized away" the variable.

Comment: Yes you're right! this is a release build!Thanks very much for the quick answer!Und viele viele Gruesse an die "alte" Heimat!! Thankfull Savvas